# azure kubernetes docker in docker: 'overlay' is not supported over overlayfs

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am trying to run a docker in docker scenario inside an azure managed kubernetes cluster(aks)

I have mounted the docker unix socket to the pod. My intention is to use aks pods as azure devops agents to build and test my project. This requires a database and a wiremock running in docker which means it will create docker network

Below you can see my current configuration:

```
Name:           my-devopsagent-javaagent-64855bb796-smpkz
Namespace:      my-devops-agents
Priority:       0
Node:           aks-default-21935887-vmss000000/10.128.0.4
Start Time:     Mon, 16 Dec 2019 14:09:04 +0200
Labels:         app=my-devopsagent-javaagent
                pod-template-hash=64855bb796
Annotations:    <none>
Status:         Running
IP:             10.128.0.28
IPs:            <none>
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/my-devopsagent-javaagent-64855bb796
Containers:
  my-devopsagent-javaagent:
    Container ID:   docker://ffffff26c3b4a92678a95f446c0ada685986f30c56138109b080
    Image:          mycontainerregistry.azurecr.io/mycompany/devopsagent/javaagent:latest
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://mycontainerregistry.azurecr.io/mycompany/devopsagent/javaagent@sha256:4422edb12d1b4bbff92bc36e7d33715222daab6ef3439cfffffff
    Port:           <none>
    Host Port:      <none>
    State:          Running
      Started:      Mon, 16 Dec 2019 14:09:06 +0200
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:
      AZP_AGENT_NAME:  CONTAINER_JAVA_AGENT
      AZP_URL:         https://dev.azure.com/mycompany
      AZP_POOL:        Default
      AZP_TOKEN:       <set to the key 'pat' in secret 'pat'>  Optional: false
    Mounts:
      /var/run/docker.sock from dockersock (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-2msgf (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             True
  ContainersReady   True
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  dockersock:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /var/run/docker.sock
    HostPathType:
  default-token-2msgf:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-2msgf
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:          <none>
```

the error I receive is

```
ERRO[0000] 'overlay' is not supported over overlayfs    
error creating libpod runtime: 'overlay' is not supported over overlayfs: backing file system is unsupported for this graph driver
```

Any ideas on how I can solve this issue?

P.S. I also tried the first comment in the [docker in docker](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/docker?view=azure-devops#) issue, meaning I tried to mount the /bin/docker which introduced different issues

Answer (score 0):

To run docker in docker, the `/var/lib/docker` filesystem cannot be the container filesystem which is built with an overlayfs. Instead, you must mount that from an external volume to a supported filesystem on the external host, either `xfs` with `ftype=1` or `ext4`. This is documented at https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/#supported-backing-filesystems

You can use a named volume on the host for this since /var/lib/docker on the host filesystem will be on a supported FS. E.g. my own DinD CLI looks like:

```
docker run -d --rm --privileged \
  -v "dind-${port}:/var/lib/docker" \
  -v "dind-${port}-ccerts:/certs/client" -e DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR=/certs \
  -v "$HOME:$HOME" \
  --name "dind-${port}" -p "127.0.0.1:${port}:2376" \
  "docker:${opt_t}-dind"
```

Note the first volume mount is something like `dind-1234:/var/lib/docker` which created a named volume for this directory in the container.